# Is there a way to obtain a strict total order of sets of ordinal rankings?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Consider a set of three ordinal rankings of three elements $A,B,C$; that is, a set of the form $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$ where, for example, $\sigma_1 = ABC, \sigma_2 = ACB, \sigma_3 = CAB$. (Here, $ABC$ is shorthand for $A\succ B\succ C$, meaning that $A$ is preferable to $B$, and $B$ is preferable to $C$.)

It's easy to see that we always can relabel the elements such that all sets can be written on the form $\{ABC,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$, and thus reducing the number of sets to $(3!)^2 = 36$, and since the order of elements in a set doesn't matter, these can in turn be reduced to 10 equivalence classes (two sets are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by relabeling the elements, e.g. $\{ABC,ABC,ABC\}$ and $\{BAC,BAC,BAC\}$):
$$P_1 = \{ABC,ABC,ABC\}, P_2 = \{ABC,ABC,ACB\},P_3 = \{ABC,ABC,BAC\},\\
P_4 = \{ABC,ABC,BCA\}, P_5 = \{ABC,ABC,CAB\}, P_6 = \{ABC,ABC,CBA\}\\
P_7 = \{ABC,ACB,BAC\}, P_8 = \{ABC,ACB,BCA\},\\
P_9 = \{ABC,BAC,CAB\},P_{10} = \{ABC,BCA,CAB\}.$$

My aim is to obtain a strict total order between these sets, with respect to "internal agreement": For instance, if I compare $P_1 = \{ABC, ABC, ABC\}$ with $P_2 = \{ABC,ABC,ACB\}$ and $P_{10} = \{ABC, BCA, CAB\}$, we intuitively think that $P_1$ has maximal internal agreement, since the rankings are identical, but in $P_{10}$ there is very little internal agreement. And $P_2$ falls somewhere in between.

Therefore, under some yet to be defined strict total order $<$, one would like to have $$P_1 < P_2< P_{10}.$$

Is there a suitable way to define such an order? It seems that we ought to take the position of the elements into account (analagous to weighted Kendall's $\tau$ for distances between ordinal rankings), so that for example,
$$P_1<P_2<P_3,$$
since it should be more "costly" to swap the first two elements in any ordering than to swap the last two elements.

In short: Can $P_1,\dots,P_{10}$ be strictly totally ordered (no ties) with respect to "internal agreement" as discussed above? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. (Even other orders with relaxed conditions, or distance functions with an strict total order of the distances, might be valuable.)

Comment: Total order and distance function are not the same thing...  A total order among the $10$ sets would be something like $P_1 < P_2 < P_3 $ etc.  Or perhaps you're trying to have a total order among the ${10 \choose 2}$ distances?

Comment: Good point. I am indeed looking for a strict total order of the sets. I have updated the question, and hopefully it is a bit more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: I have heard of Kendall's $\tau$ but I have not heard of the weighted version, but presumably it's just like the unweighted version and is a distance function between two permutations $\pi$ and $\sigma$, call it $d(\pi, \sigma)$.  Then one obvious thing is something like for $P = \{\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3\}$ we value it as $D(P) = d(\pi_1, \pi_2) + d(\pi_2, \pi_3) + d(\pi_1, \pi_3)$, i.e. sum of the $3$ distances.  Another obvious thing is $\min_i \sum_{j \neq i} d(\pi_i, \pi_j)$ i.e sum of the $2$ shorter distances - alternatively interpreted as sum of distances from the "more centered" $\pi$.

Comment: Instead of adding the distances, you can multiply them, combine them in some weighted form, whatever you like.  However, there is no guarantee any version would give a unique value for each $P$, i.e. would lead to a total order.  Indeed, say we pick the sum of $3$ distances version, and two different $P$ evaluate to the same $D(P)$, in that case on what basis do you even want to separate them and say one is better than the other?

Comment: One more idea is to take the $3$ distances and sort them.  So each $D(P)$ is a $3$-vector.  Assuming the ten sorted $3$-vectors are different, you can order them lexicographically, i.e. $(1,2,10) < (1,3,4)$ or choose some other natural order.  But I don't know that the $3$-vectors are gonna be all different.  (They may well be, but  we have to prove it first.)

Comment: These are all nice suggestions. I have tried the sum-of-distances version, but it lead to ties (at least with the specific weight function I chose) and counter-intuitive orders. The idea of lexicographic order or (similar) might be worth to investigate though. But it seems like there should be a lot of structure hiding in these sets, suggesting some axiomatic approach...

Comment: (And yes, weighted Kendall's $\tau$ is like the original version, but we put weights, via an auxiliary weight function, on different swaps to capture that swaps closer to the head of the permutation are costlier.)

Comment: I would agree there is structure, which maybe suggests there should be some axiomatic approach.  But I also thought what you have is a _design_ problem.  E.g. if in $P: \pi_1, \pi_2$ agree very well but $\pi_3$ is very different, vs in $P'$ all three of them agree middling well, which has better internal agreement? That is not really a math problem, but rather a design choice. You seem to have a gut feel about how to rank $P$ vs $P'$, but I'm guessing that's based on an application you have in mind. Lexicographical can be tweaked to do $P < P'$ or the reverse, but that's again a choice.